# Transpose and Groupby pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to transpose pandas columns and apply a Groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4'], 
                   'Code1' : ['X60', np.nan, 'X66', np.nan], 
                   'Code2' : [np.nan, 'X64', 'X78', np.nan],
                   'Code3' : [np.nan, 'X66', 'X81', 'X59'],
                   'Code4' : [np.nan, np.nan, 'X38', 'X60']})
df

    ID      Code1   Code2   Code3   Code4
0   ID1     X60     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   ID2     NaN     X64     X66     NaN
2   ID3     X66     X78     X81     X38
3   ID4     NaN     NaN     X59     X60
```

How can I achieve this expected output ?

```
Code NB ID
X38  1  ID3
X59  1  ID4
X60  2  ID1, ID4 
X64  1  ID2
X66  2  ID2, ID3
X78  1  ID3
X81  1  ID3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape with remove missing values and count values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), last [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) with [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and
[`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for 2 columns DataFrame:

```
df = df.stack().value_counts().sort_index().rename_axis('Code').reset_index(name='NB')
print (df)
  Code  NB
0  X38   1
1  X59   1
2  X60   2
3  X64   1
4  X66   2
5  X78   1
6  X81   1
```

EDIT: Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then aggregate by `size` and `join` in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = (df.melt('ID', value_name='Code')
        .groupby('Code', as_index=False)
        .agg(NB=('Code','size'), ID=('ID',', '.join)))
print (df)
  Code  NB        ID
0  X38   1       ID3
1  X59   1       ID4
2  X60   2  ID1, ID4
3  X64   1       ID2
4  X66   2  ID3, ID2
5  X78   1       ID3
6  X81   1       ID3
```

Comment: @jezrael, with a groupby, you probably do not need to use dropna, since groupby will ignore them, unless you explicitly set `dropna=False`

Answer (score 1):

one option is to transform the data into long form, with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) before grouping:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = 'ID', 
    names_to = 'Code', 
    names_pattern = ['Code'])
.groupby('Code')
.agg(NB = ('ID', 'size'), ID = ('ID', ','.join))
)
      NB       ID
Code
X38    1      ID3
X59    1      ID4
X60    2  ID1,ID4
X64    1      ID2
X66    2  ID3,ID2
X78    1      ID3
X81    1      ID3
```